# Playing youtube video using a webview in android ICS Error: "OnBufferingUpdateListener is null"

Tags: android, webview, youtube, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am using a webview and google API for youtube (iframe) to play youtube videos.
Everything is fine as long as I use honeycomb but as soon as I switch to ICS I receive the error below:
Error: "OnBufferingUpdateListener is null"

has anyone had the same issue and how to resolve it?
(I should say that despite the error the app continues working.)

Thanks,